# Trouble Monitoring Performance Metrics for Native Executables Built with GraalVM

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm currently working with native executables created using GraalVM, and I'm interested in monitoring various performance metrics, such as CPU usage, thread activity, and memory usage. However, when I run the application, it doesn't appear in VisualVM's local application list.

When i attempt to establish a manual connection using "Add JMX Connection," the following stack trace was displayed in the application's running terminal.

```
2023-10-26T21:58:48.560+05:45  INFO 15900 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [JRMI0x000x02K...]. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:407) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[graalvm.exe:10.1.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[graalvm.exe:10.1.15]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[na:na]
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[graalvm.exe:na]
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:807) ~[graalvm.exe:na]
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsPlatformThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsPlatformThreads.java:179) ~[na:na]
```

I'd like to understand how to effectively monitor the performance of GraalVM native images. What tools and approaches can I use to achieve this? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: JMX should be supported, as well as JFR. Here are [some guides](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/guides/?topic=monitor). Did you build your image with `--enable-monitoring`?

Comment: I've generated an image of a Spring Boot application using Gradle's nativeCompile. Could you please guide me on how to utilize the '--enable-monitoring' option?

Answer (score 0):

what is available in Native Image in terms of monitoring is the following:

- JFR
- jvmstat
- JMX (experimental)
- heap dump.

You need to enable monitoring with a flag, for example `--enable-monitoring=jvmstat`. For what you are looking to monitor, jvmstat and VisualVM would be a good fit.

[Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) should work with GraalVM as well.

Depending on how exactly you want to monitor these metrics, you can also use external tooling, such as [psrecord](https://github.com/astrofrog/psrecord).

Comment: Is it possible to utilize the --enable-monitoring=jvmstat flag with Gradle's nativeCompile task? I encountered an error when attempting to do this.                                                             
            -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61

Comment: yes, you can pass additional arguments like so:
graalvmNative {
    binaries {
        main {
            buildArgs.add(...)
        }
        test {
            buildArgs.add(...)
        }
    }
    binaries.all {
        buildArgs.add(...)
    }
}

regarding your error, are you using GraalVM for JDK 21? That looks to me like a Gradle & Java 21 compatibility issue, try using toolchains: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html